# Issues hiding already appended stuff

Tags: jquery

When I press showAllButton I load 8 profiles from my array; 4 women and 4 men.

Then when I press showAllMenBtn I load the 4 male profiles again.

But they stack on top of what already appended.

How can I make it so they replace the already appended profiles?

I've tried a lot of `.toogle()` and `.hide()` without any success.

Thanks in advance:)

```
$("#showAllBtn").click(function(){

    $(allProfiles).each(function(index, profile){

        let profileImg = $("<img>", {src:`${profile.imageSrc}`});            
        let newName = profileName = profile.name;
        let newAge = profileAge = profile.age;
        let newGender = profileGender = profile.gender;
        let newInterests = profileInterests = profile.description;

        $("#profileSection").append(profileImg, newName, newAge, newGender, newInterests);


    })

});

$("#showAllMenBtn").click(function(){   


    $(maleProfiles).each(function(index, profile){

        let profileImg = $("<img>", {src:`${profile.imageSrc}`});            
        let newName = profileName = profile.name;
        let newAge = profileAge = profile.age;
        let newGender = profileGender = profile.gender;
        let newInterests = profileInterests = profile.description;


        $("#profileSection").append(profileImg, newName, newAge, newGender, newInterests);
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
$("#showAllBtn").click(function(){

    $("#profileSection").html("");
    $(allProfiles).each(function(index, profile){

        let profileImg = $("<img>", {src:`${profile.imageSrc}`});            
        let newName = profileName = profile.name;
        let newAge = profileAge = profile.age;
        let newGender = profileGender = profile.gender;
        let newInterests = profileInterests = profile.description;

        $("#profileSection").append(profileImg, newName, newAge, newGender, newInterests);


    })

});

$("#showAllMenBtn").click(function(){   
   $("#profileSection").html("");

    $(maleProfiles).each(function(index, profile){

        let profileImg = $("<img>", {src:`${profile.imageSrc}`});            
        let newName = profileName = profile.name;
        let newAge = profileAge = profile.age;
        let newGender = profileGender = profile.gender;
        let newInterests = profileInterests = profile.description;


        $("#profileSection").append(profileImg, newName, newAge, newGender, newInterests);
    })

});
```

Comment: why do you think it will work? add some explanation.

Comment: before you append, you need to empty your $("#profileSection").html("");

Comment: @Haugens  no need to do one extra line of code. `.html()` in the end will work perfectly. Try my answer to confirm.

Answer (score 4):

In second click handler  use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#profileSection").html(profileImg, newName, newAge, newGender, newInterests);
```

***Note:-*** `.html()` remove the older data and then add new data inside given element (selector)

So second code needs to be like this:-

```
$("#showAllMenBtn").click(function(){   

    $(maleProfiles).each(function(index, profile){

        let profileImg = $("<img>", {src:`${profile.imageSrc}`});            
        let newName = profileName = profile.name;
        let newAge = profileAge = profile.age;
        let newGender = profileGender = profile.gender;
        let newInterests = profileInterests = profile.description;

        $("#profileSection").html(profileImg, newName, newAge, newGender, newInterests);
    })
});
```